# Change display content based on dropdown selection

Tags: jquery, css, knockout.js

So I have a dropdown that offers two different view of the same information and I wanted to know how I could wire up my dropdown selection to change which `div` is being displayed to the user while hiding the other. Here is what I have so far..

```
<select data-bind="options: displays, value: selectedDisplay, optionsText: 'displayOption'"></select>
```

The display options I have are: 'Display 1' and 'Display 2'

Then I have two `div`'s each for a display option.

```
<div id="display1">.....</div>
<div id="display2">.....</div>
```

By default I will be having `display1` be displayed while having `display2` hidden until the user selects a different display then the one not in use will be hidden.

This is what I have for my view model:

```
self.displays = ko.observableArray();
self.selectedView = ko.observable();

var sampleData = {

        displays: [
            {
                display1: 'Display 1'
            },
            {
                display2: 'Display 2'
            }
        ]
    };
```

Comment: Do you want to change the selected item in your `select` dropdown?

Comment: @tibzon no i would like to display which div is being visible based on the selected dropdown. So if i select display 1 in my dropdown then i will have the div id="display1" displayed and div id="display2" hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to apply a `visible` binding to each div and make it test the `selectedDisplay` value.

```js
var vm = {
  selectedDisplay: ko.observable(),
  displays: [
    1, 2
  ]
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: displays, value: selectedDisplay"></select>
<div data-bind="visible:selectedDisplay() == 1">This is Div 1</div>
<div data-bind="visible:selectedDisplay() == 2">You see Div 2</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info. I tried to implement this but now i get the dropdown but nothing is being displayed on the page. neither display options is showing and i am not getting any errors in my console either.

Comment: Sounds like the values of the select options don't match the values being used in the comparison.

Comment: @072et You will probably need to use the `optionsValue` binding to make the selected value be what you want it to be.